# can the Browse option under a ADO/ODBC connection can be programatically done in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ado.net

So I need to pass around 700k ids (each one has a size of 19 characters) in a query to retrieve the data from a Vertica DB, I can use ODBC or ADO Connections in SSIS, the only way I found available to do this was create dynamically a .sql file through a script. I thought I could then have the connection Source Editor load the file for the SQL Command text. The first part is done and clean, I create the file and the source reads the sql from the file and retrieve the information after the script finish the creation of the sql command and save it into a .sql file, however when I rewrite the new file, the Connection Source don't read the new file(I keep the same file name just overwrite the content), I usually load the .sql file through the Browse option, next to the Builder query inside the ODBC Source Editor. My question is, is there a way to have this forcibly look at the .sql file to load the content and load it in the sql command text every time I loop through the data flowTask?   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the .sql file into a variable. The simplest is probably to read the SQL file using a Script Task:

1. Create 2 variables: **scriptPath** (String) to store the location of the SQL script, and **sqlQuery** (String) to store the SQL script itself.
2. Create a Script Task and provide it Read/Write access to these variables.
3. Implement the code to read the SQL script file. Here's an example in VB .Net (code not tested):

```
Dim filePath As String
filePath = Cstr(Me.Dts.Variables("scriptPath").Value)

Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(filePath)
Dim StreamText As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
Me.Dts.Variables("sqlQuery").Value = StreamText
```

4. You can now use the **sqlQuery** variable in your ADO connect.

Comment: do you know if there is any size limitation in the variable, we are talking about 700k records that are around 20 charaters each + the query itself that will go into this variable( the actual .sql file)?

Comment: @JuanCarlosArayaPortuguez, it will probably work, but you'll have to try it out. Perhaps there is a better way to retrieve the data you need. 1. Can you retrieve *all* records from source DB and then filter on SQL Server (or retrieve a sufficiently smaller sub-set, eg all records created/modified in the past 12 months)?

Comment: 2. Can you set up a Linked Server on SQL Server to the source DB (see [create linked server to vertica](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52521/)), create a table on SQL Server with your required ID's, then query using `OPENQUERY` and use [`EXISTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql) operator or `INNER JOIN` (whichever you prefer)?

Comment: OPENQUERY has a big/small problem, it only accepts queries of 8000 characters length top, after that, it will truncate anything else and the query will fail...  my current process is a loop of around 29k queries in a SSIS package and it takes like a whole day... while if I could do it the way I am describing it will take 1 or 2 hours top..

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows you to use linked servers in complex queries that contain `JOIN` clauses.

### Linked Server

Configure a Linked Server to your Vertica DB (see [create linked server to vertica](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52521/)).

### Local reference table

Create a local table in your *destination* SQL Server database and populate it with your required ID's. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.tRef_Vertica_Transaction_Ids(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
-- Note: Having an index is important! It affects the query plan.
INSERT INTO dbo.tRef_Vertica_Transaction_Ids
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(123),(333),(999) -- Insert your ID's here
) Vals(v)
```

## OPENQUERY

Now use [OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql) to retrieve your data. Experiment with several query types to identify what works fastest:

### OPENQUERY with WHERE EXISTS

```
SELECT v.*
FROM OPENQUERY([VerticaDB], 'SELECT * FROM SourceTable') v
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.tRef_Vertica_Transaction_Ids ref
    WHERE ref.ID = v.ID
)
```

### OPENQUERY with INNER JOIN

```
SELECT v.*
FROM OPENQUERY([VerticaDB], 'SELECT * FROM SourceTable') v
INNER JOIN dbo.tRef_Vertica_Transaction_Ids ref
    ON ref.ID = v.ID
```

### OPENQUERY with INNER REMOTE JOIN

```
SELECT v.*
FROM OPENQUERY([VerticaDB], 'SELECT * FROM SourceTable') v
INNER REMOTE JOIN dbo.tRef_Vertica_Transaction_Ids ref
    ON ref.ID = v.ID
```

REMOTE JOIN forces the join operation to be performed on the site of the right table.

### Join hints

SQL Server provides you with these join hints:

- INNER MERGE JOIN
- INNER REMOTE JOIN
- INNER LOOP JOIN
- INNER HASH JOIN

More info about each at [Join Hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-join).

You will probably get best performance with `MERGE JOIN` or `REMOTE JOIN`, but you won't know until you try.

### Constrain your query

Yes, you can do `SELECT * FROM SourceTable`, but this probably not the best idea. You can probably construct a WHERE clause that will significantly reduce your result-set and make the JOIN more efficient. For example, you may be able to restrict your result-set by specifying something like `WHERE RecordCreatedDate > '2016-01-01'`.

One you have a working query, store it in a view.

Comment: Thanks I will try your recommendation, I am still skeptical with openQuery.. I believe they have a limitation of 8000 charaters lenght max? anyway the information seems pretty good, so I will try and Ill let you know the results